# Increasing fetchLimit and sorting results when using readWithQueryString Azure's call

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-mobile-services

I need to **query** some data from my **Azure Mobile Service**. What I know so far is that I use the **MSQuery** call I can change the **fetchLimit** and **orderBy** but not add the **systemProperties** in the returned data. When using **readWithQueryString** I have been able to fetch those systemProperties but not to change the fetch limit nor sort results.
Im guessing you can add some more query-parameters when using readWithQueryString but I havent found any information of how to do such a thing.
Im working on an IOS app using **swift** in XCode.

This is using a class that allows you fetch the systemProperties I havent been able to add an orderBy and fetchLimit change to the URL:

```
itemTable.readWithQueryString("https://mymobileService.azure-mobile.net/tables/tableName?__systemProperties=createdAt")
```

And this would be using a query class that doesnt allow you to get the systemProperties:

```
var query = itemTable.query()
    query.fetchLimit = 300
    query.orderByDescending("__createdAt")
```

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many things I got it to work like this:

```
itemTable.readWithQueryString("https://serviceName.azure-mobile.net/tables/TableName?__systemProperties=createdAt&$top=100&$orderby=__createdAt%20desc")
```

I pretty much had to guess since there is not much documentation for this on Azure.